# What is the difference between loaded and unloaded buffers?

Tags: buffers, autocompletion

I was looking at the documentation for the 'complete' option, and I found it a bit confusing:

```
.   scan the current buffer ('wrapscan' is ignored)
w   scan buffers from other windows
b   scan other loaded buffers that are in the buffer list
u   scan the unloaded buffers that are in the buffer list
U   scan the buffers that are not in the buffer list
k   scan the files given with the 'dictionary' option
kspell  use the currently active spell checking |spell|
k{dict} scan the file {dict}.  Several "k" flags can be given, patterns are valid too.  For example:  
        :set cpt=k/usr/dict/*,k~/spanish
s   scan the files given with the 'thesaurus' option
s{tsr}  scan the file {tsr}.  Several "s" flags can be given, patterns are valid too.
i   scan current and included files
d   scan current and included files for defined name or macro |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D|
]   tag completion
t   same as "]"
```

What is the difference between `b`, `u` and `U`? I thought as soon as you did either `:e file/path` or `:badd file/path`, everything gets "loaded" into memory for editing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation with buffers is quite complicated. Use `:ls` (of `:buffers`) to inspect them.

There can be the following states:

1. Active buffer --- both loaded into RAM and shown in (at least one) window. This is what you normally got after `:e filename`, `:buffer N` and so on. (flagged "a" by `:ls`; also when it's in active window, it's flagged by "%")
2. Hidden buffer --- fully loaded but nowhere shown, except the buffer list. This is when you call `bufload()` to load a new buffer without showing it, or `:hide` an existing window/buffer, or do `:quit` while `set hidden` or `setlocal bufhidden=hide` etc. (flagged "h" by `:ls`)
3. Unloaded buffer --- "the data stream" is unloaded from RAM, but all other stuff, such as local variables, options, bookmarks etc., is still preserved. This is what you get after `:bunload`, or (if `set nohidden`) when switching buffers by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>, or do `:quit!` etc. (no special flag in `:ls`, except maybe `#`).
4. Unlisted buffer --- this is just a special flag which is honoured by `:ls` command: unlisted buffers are not shown unless `:ls!` is specifed. (flagged "u" by `:ls!`)

In fact, any buffer has two independent flags: loaded and listed. "Loaded and nolisted" is a typical value for special buffers such as "help", so they are visible but not normally shown by `:ls`; "unloaded and nolisted" is set when a buffer is deleted.

5. Deleted buffer --- this is both unloaded and unlisted buffer. "The data stream" is unloaded from RAM, and all buffer-local variables and options are erased. However, all local bookmarks are still intact alongside with "filename" and "buffer number". This is what you get after `:bdelete`. Also the same fate awaits for all "nofile" and "unnamed" buffers - they are not just unloaded but also deleted (also flagged "u" by `:ls!`, as they all are unlisted too).
6. Wiped buffer --- this is a full extermination, no mercy, no trace in history. Done by `:bwipeout`.

Comment: For buffers, what are "local variables, options, bookmarks etc."? Could you provide a short explanation; or where I can read about this? A Google search gives vague results.

Comment: @herophant Please, forget about google and start to use the help system: `:h buffer-variable`, `:h local-options` and so on.

Comment: What does it mean exactly for a buffer's "data stream" to be unloaded from RAM? Since you can easily "re-load" an unloaded (but still listed) buffer at a moments notice with navigation commands like `:bnext`, `:bprev`, or `:[N]b`, a buffer being in an inactive state is effectively the same as a buffer in a hidden state. Are there some commands/operations you can perform on hidden buffers that you cannot perform on unloaded buffers?

Comment: @NicholasCousar Buffer = data + metadata. How much of metadata is freed or kept depends on buftype and operation. Only wipeout destroys everything including "name" and "number".

Comment: Say I call `:enew` to a buffer `[No Name]`, and from the `:ls!` it's an active buffer and sometimes it has a `#`-sign on it. So what's this? Apparently, this buffer is not loaded with any file so it should always be an unloaded buffer based on my reading of your answer(I might misunderstand some points). This is the reason I'm interested in unloaded-listed buffers because these `[No Name]`s are categorized into this type in my current understanding.

Comment: @job_start No, in Vim speak it is loaded. You got it wrong. "Loaded" = "contents is not null".

Comment: OK, now I understood. So do you mean there is a data structure allocated there to store what I will type, even if the content of it is currently empty?

Comment: You can go on and inspect C code, if you really wish. This is what OpenSource stands for. There's buffer struct that has contents field, that may be null, or it may be line array, that may be empty (or it has single empty "virtual" line - I don't remember all the details and I don't need to). Kind of that.

Answer (score 6):

A buffer is `listed` if it's in the buffer list, you can see it in [:h :buffers](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abuffers) , you can refer to it with [:h :buffer](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abuffer) , [:h :bnext](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abnext) , etc . It's controled by setting [:h 'buflisted'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27buflisted%27) .

A buffer is `loaded` if the corresponding file is loaded into memory.

Not all buffers should be `listed`, e.g. `help` type buffer is not listed, as no one wants to refer to it with [:h :buffer](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abuffer) .

Not all buffers should be `loaded`, as `load` is not free, it cost time and memory, it doesn't make sense to load a buffer that you might not use at all.

`:e file/path` create a `listed` and `loaded` buffer.

`:badd file/path` create a `listed` but not `loaded` buffer.

`:args a b c d` creates 4 buffers, all of them `listed`, but only `a` is loaded.

`:bunload` unload buffer.

`:bdelete` unload buffer, remove it in the buffer list, clear options, variables, maps, abbreviations.

`:bwipe` unload buffer, remove it in the buffer list, wipe everything.

You can check buffer info with [:h getbufinfo()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getbufinfo%28%29) .

You can also check unlisted buffer with `:buffers!`.

Comment: What does `:b file/path` do? I'm guessing it edits `file/path` since it shows up on the terminal screen. Say you only have one window and you are editing `file/path`. You execute `:b file/path2`. Now you certainly have `file/path2` loaded since you are editing it, but what happened to `file/path`? Has it been unloaded and that memory freed?

Comment: Original buffer (`file/path`) will be `:h abondon` , it's unloaded only if `'hidden'` is off.